# How to remove items from Activerecord query resultset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I get a resultset from a Rails find query.  I want to iterate over that resultset and depending on certain criteria drop records from that resultset before passing it on for further processing.  The additional criteria are external to the data held in the database and hence I can't include them in the original 'find' query.

Note I don't want to delete any records from the database just remove them from the resultset.

Please can someone give me the code to do that.

Comment: Did you ever find what you were looking for ?

Comment: This can be closed as "too broad" or "recommendation for off-site resource".

Answer (score 32):

Use [reject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000258) as in

```
Model.find_all_by_xxx().reject { |r| r.something? }
```

Comment: This won't work, as `find_by_xxx` returns a single record. You want `find_all_by_xxx`.

Comment: @RyanBigg oops, you're right. I was working on a Doctrine project when answered, in which `find_by_xxx` returns a collection. Edited.

Answer (score 6):

```
set = MyObject.find(...)
set = set.reject{|s| ... }
```

or

```
set = set.select{|s| ... }
```

Comment: When I do this `set` seems to be converted into an `array`?

Comment: `find` only returns one object. Perhaps you want `MyObject.all` or `MyObject.where`

Comment: @DylanVanderBerg do you realize that this question is about RoR v1 or v2? :)

Answer (score 2):

If some processing must be done in application code that SQL can not do, and the result must be a changed query object, re-querying the objects by `id` might be a (very memory inefficient) option.

```
needed_ids = Model.where(<some original query>).map{|r| r.something? ? r.id : nil }.compact
new_collection = Model.where(id: needed_ids)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `delete_at` too:

```
irb(main):005:0> c = Category.all
Category Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" 
=> [#<Category id: 1, name: "15 anos", description: nil, created_at: "2011-09-22 04:52:53", updated_at: "2011-09-22 04:52:53">]
irb(main):006:0> c.delete_at(0)
=> #<Category id: 1, name: "15 anos", description: nil, created_at: "2011-09-22 04:52:53", updated_at: "2011-09-22 04:52:53">
irb(main):007:0> c
=> []
```

Comment: This one will delete the entry from the database, right?

Comment: He asked to remove from an active record object, not delete from the database! Be careful with this one!